# Multiple row selection in react-table not working

Tags: react-table

multiple selection is not working for react-table in my local setup. but the same is working stackbiltz. Can anyone download the code from stackbiltz and run the same in local and let me know what i need to do in local to make it work

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xjzb2d

Answer (score 0):

Please dis-regard the question. The issues was due to https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12856. After removing React.StrictMode everything works properly